# Is the image of a neighbourhood in the product topology under a projection a neighbourhood?

Tags: general-topology, elementary-set-theory, solution-verification

I'm trying to show that in an arbitrary product $\prod_iX_i$ of topological spaces, the closure of a product of sets is the product of the respective closures, i.e. that $\overline{\prod_iA_i}=\prod_i\overline{A_i}$. One direction of this is easy, as the product of closures is a closed set in the product topology and contains $\prod_iA_i$, therefore we have the inclusion $\subset$. To show $\supset$ I was trying to show that if $x\notin\overline{\prod_iA_i}$, then $x\notin\prod_i\overline{A_i}$. By assumption, there exists a neighbourhood $N$ of $x$ that does not intersect $\prod_iA_i$. This implies that there exists an $i$, such that $\pi_i(N)\cap A_i=\emptyset$. If $\pi_i(N)$ were a neighbourhood of $x_i$, this would imply that $x_i\notin\overline{A_i}$ and hence that $x\notin\prod_i\overline{A_i}$.

I feel like this assumption is plausible, since the projection is better-behaved than most continuous functions (if I recall correctly, it is an open map), but I am not 100% sure.

Edit: I was just thinking, since the product topology is generated by products of open sets (where all but finitely many are equalto $X_i$), i.e. sets of the form $\prod_iO_i$, where all but finitely many of the $O_i$ are equal to $X_i$, $N$ being a neighbourhood of $x$ would imply there has to be a set of this form around $x$ contained in $N$, so projecting would yield $x_i\in O_i\subset\pi_i(N)$ and this seems to work when the product is finite and $O_i\neq X_i$, but what to do if the product is infinite and $O_i=X_i$?

Edit $2$: If $O_i=X_i$, then $\pi_i(N)\cap A_i$ cannot be empty, but there has to exist such an $i$, therefore there must exist an $i$ with $O_i\neq X_i$ and the rest follows as mentioned above. Is this reasoning correct?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The image under $\pi_i$ of a basic open set is open in $X_i$. Since any open set in the product is a union of basic open sets its image under $\pi_i$ is a union of open sets in $X_i$ and hence it is open. Now $x_i=\pi_i(x)\in \pi_i(N)$ so $\pi_i(N)$ is a neighborhood of $x_i$.

Comment: So one does not need to differentiate between cases $O_i\neq X_i$ and $O_i=X_i$ in the case of an infinite product $\prod_iX_i$?

Comment: No. That is where you made things more complicated. The image of $\prod U_j$ is always open and you don't care whether $U_j$'s are equal to $X_j$ or not.  @V.Ch.

Comment: Alright, thanks!

Comment: I'm trying now to show that the interior of a product is contained in the product of interiors. Would arguing componentwise, as above, be correct? That is, $x\in(\prod_iA_i)^\circ$ implies $x_i\in O_i\subset A_i$, which implies $x_i\in O_i\subset A_i^\circ$ and finally $x\in\prod_iA_i^\circ$?

Comment: @V.Ch. Yes, that is correct.